# Envio de emails apartir do meu web site php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Boa tarde tenho a seguinte duvida eu estoua  desenvolver um web site e pretendo que numa das zonas ele ao clicar num botao recolha os dados dae uma tabela da base de dados referente a esse id desse cliente mas nao sei como fazelo enviar email para um email do meu dominio ja consegui mas e possivel enviar para outros emails?
ou tenho de instalar algo para o poder fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, sempre para envio de emails com PHP puro é recomendável o uso de uma biblioteca que facilite tudo para você. Eu recomendo o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Você só precisa adicionar as configurações de SMTP e enviar seu enviar seu email. Na própria página do Github já demonstra um envio simples.

Comment: Muito obrigado esclareceu na perfeição, obrigado pela ajuda e paciência!